# How to Parse IPAddress on C# with Framework 4.6

Tags: c#

How is the correct way to Parse an IPAddress from String to System.Net.IPAddress on C# with Framework 4.6.

I am trying to implement with Visual Studio 2017 NuGet TCPSimple a TCP/IP Server and Client for testing purposes, but I got a System.FormatException "Input string was not in a correct format".

I have tried different approaches, but they're not working at all!

```
    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtStatus.Text += "Server starting...";

        //var address = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("10.0.11.174").GetAddressBytes();
        //long m_Address = ((address[3] << 24 | address[2] << 16 | address[1] << 8 | address[0]) & 0x0FFFFFFFF);
        System.Net.IPAddress ip = new System.Net.IPAddress(long.Parse(txtHost.Text));
        //System.Net.IPAddress ip = new System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        server.Start(ip,Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text));
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an [IPAddress.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) method in the .NET framework to handle this.

```
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(txtHost.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) for the Parse() method:

```
public static IPAddress Parse(
    string ipString
)
```

It's static, and it expects a string. So,

```
System.Net.IPAddress ip = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(txtHost.Text);
```

should do the trick. If this throws a FormatException error it's the user's fault, so catch the exception and display a friendly error message.

Comment: It seemed to me that in       System.Net.IPAddress ip = new System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(txtHost.Text);       the problem was the "new" instruction so it couldnt find the Parse on the System.Net.IPAddress.....

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using `IPAdress.TryParse()` in case you provide an invalid IP.  Something like:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string goodIp = "127.0.0.1";
        string badIp = "127.0.O.1";

        IPAddress ip;
        if (IPAddress.TryParse(goodIp, out ip))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start your server");
        }

        if (!IPAddress.TryParse(badIp, out ip))
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Bad IP");
        }
    }
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DldnSj)